# Paste code from internet, automatic change from class to className in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using WebStorm, and it has a feature that automatically changes all occurences of "class" to "className" when using .jsx/.tsx. Is there a plugin that does the similar thing in VS Code?

Comment: do you found this yet? i need to know